# Problem with inputs with IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I have following code in html:

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left;margin:0.5em">
    <span class="title">Label1</span><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name1" size="8" />
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;margin:0.5em">
    <span class="title">Label2</span><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name2" size="12" />
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;margin:0.5em">
    <span class="title">Label3</span><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name3" size="12" />
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;margin:0.5em">      
    <span class="title">Label4</span><br/>
    <select name="name4">
      <option value="m">value1</option>
      <option value="f">value2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;margin:0.5em">
    <span class="title">Label5</span><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name5" size="8" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome it looks all right:
[firefox and chrome look http://jakub.sturc.info/data/so-labeled-inputs-chrome.png](http://jakub.sturc.info/data/so-labeled-inputs-chrome.png)

However in Internet Explorer 7 it is slightly malformed:
[malformed IE7 look look http://jakub.sturc.info/data/so-labeled-inputs-ie7.png](http://jakub.sturc.info/data/so-labeled-inputs-ie7.png)

Do you have any tips how to force IE to render desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are using no reset css I would recommend a shortcut would be to change the margin to padding instead on the wrapper divs which will be consistent between browsers.

Not the best technique but simplest in your case.

Comment: I am amazed how much IE problems can be solved by altering paddings and margins. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

I think Richard has given you the correct answer, this seems to work:

```
<div style="float:left;padding:0.5em">
<span class="title">Label1</span><br/>
<input type="text" name="name1" size="8" />
</div>
```

The problem must be that IE is not applying the margin to the span tag but for some reason does apply the padding.